# Apache, LetsEncrypt & Vrtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

I am installing a **letsencrypt** server on my own server for a virtual host.

After creating the certificate successfully, I get a message like:

```
Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem
Your key file has been saved at:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem
```

(I have changed the domain to protect the, well, for no reason, actually).

When I look in the directory, I find the following

```
ls /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net
cert.pem@  chain.pem@  fullchain.pem@  privkey.pem@  README
```

So, I have four links pointing to four real files.

In my `.conf` file I have something like this (using Version 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.net:443
    ServerAlias *.example.net
    ServerAdmin mark@example.net
    VirtualDocumentRoot /data/httpd/html/example.net/%-3

    SSLEngine on

#   Version 1

    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/chain.pem

#   Version 2

#   SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem
#   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

I have seen other documentation using Version 2.

The question is: given that the message mentions only two files, and that there are really four files, what is the correct configuration for using **letsencrypt** with a Virtual Host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat cert.pem chain.pem` is equivalent to `cat fullchain.pem`. In other words, the fullchain.pem file is just the combination of cert.pem and chain.pem. See the following [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/347588/how-do-ssl-chains-work) for more about SSL certificate chains.

I'm not certain on the Apache end but it seems like Version 1 simply took in the two files (cert.pem and chain.pem) and then internally concatenated them while Version 2 just asks for the concatenated version. I would assume most web servers now just ask for the SSLCertificateFile (aka the "fullchain.pem") and the private key.

Comment: Thanks for that. I’ll opt for version 2 as it’s simpler, and the letsencrypt message seems to prefer it.